# Camera rotation for multiplayer game

Tags: c#, camera, unity-game-engine

I am trying to work with a "mouse look/orbit" script, but I have having issues.  My game has four cameras.  The are centered around a table, and represent a player.  This is a multiplayer card game, so you can imagine players around a four sided table.  Each camera is facing a different direction.  In my inspector, I have an empty object that I tie this script to.  Inside this object, is my camera (so, four object, each containing a camera).  Here is the script:

```
public class MouseOrbitImproved : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
    public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
    public float sensitivityX = 3F;
    public float sensitivityY = 3F;
    public float minimumX = -360F;
    public float maximumX = 360F;
    public float minimumY = -10.0F;
    public float maximumY = 60F;
    public string playerCamera;

    float rotationX = 0F;
    float rotationY = 0F;
    Quaternion originalRotation;
    private Rigidbody rigidBody;
    public float _distance = 20.0f;


    //Control the speed of zooming and dezooming.
    public float _zoomStep = 1.0f;

    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
        {
            if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
            {
                // Read the mouse input axis
                rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
                rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
                rotationX = ClampAngle(rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);
                rotationY = ClampAngle(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
                Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationX, Vector3.up);
                Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationY, -Vector3.right);
                transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion * yQuaternion;
            }
            else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
            {
                rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
                rotationX = ClampAngle(rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);
                Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationX, Vector3.up);
                transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion;
            }
            else
            {
                rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
                rotationY = ClampAngle(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
                Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-rotationY, Vector3.right);
                transform.localRotation = originalRotation * yQuaternion;
            }
        }       

    }
    void Start()
    {
        // Make the rigid body not change rotation
        string camName = playerCamera + "CameraHolder";     
         GameObject eastCamera = GameObject.FindWithTag(camName);
        if (eastCamera)
        {
            originalRotation = eastCamera.transform.localRotation;

        }
    }
    public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360F)
             angle += 360F;
        if (angle > 360F)
             angle -= 360F;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
}
```

This script works fine for the first player but for everyone else, the axis on which the camera rotates gets mixed up (I assume because it like a "mirror" of the original).  So, how can I account for the change in direction the camera points in, with this script?  I've tried to account for this in the Start function, but this does not seem to help.

thanks

**EDIT**

After working with HRISTO, this is what I ended up doing:

1. I stopped using four cameras, and just used one.  I then have a vector array for direction and rotation, for each of the four "players"
2. When the game loads, I set the camera to the correct rotation/direction array, based on the player joining the game.
3. In my camera script, I added:

   ```
   private void LateUpdate()
   {
       GameObject controller = GameObject.FindWithTag("controller");
       GameController playerScript = controller.GetComponent<GameController>();
       int playerId = playerScript.getPlayerId();            
       string playerDirection = playerScript.getPlayerDirectionByID(playerId);
       DebugConsole.Log("Player Direction = " + playerDirection);

       if (playerDirection == "EAST")
       {
           originalRotation = playerScript.eastCameraRotaion;
           originalPosition = playerScript.eastCameraVector;
       }
       else if (playerDirection == "WEST")
       {
           originalRotation = playerScript.westCameraRotaion;
           originalPosition = playerScript.westCameraVector;
       }
       else if (playerDirection == "NORTH")
       {
           originalRotation = playerScript.northCameraRotaion;
           originalPosition = playerScript.northCameraVector;
       }
       else if (playerDirection == "SOUTH")
       {
           originalRotation = playerScript.southCameraRotaion;
           originalPosition = playerScript.southCameraVector;
       }
   ```

   }

Originally, I was doing this in the Start method, but realized that the camera script got loaded when the Scene was loaded, before a player ever got added to the game.  As such, there was no way to know which vectors to use.  By doing this in the Update method, I could check which directions/rotations to use.

Comment: Did you try replacing `transform.localRotation` with `transform.rotation` in your entire script?

Comment: @Hristo hello and thanks for the reply.  I have tried as you suggested but this did not help

Comment: Is this a particularly difficult script or am I not explaining well enough?  Or is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Could you explain how exactly does it get mixed up? Give an example please.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is a multiplayer (4 player) game.  So, when I test, I have four windows open.  In the first window, the rotation works fine.  but in all the others, the rotations seem to be moving in different directions, at the wrong angles.  In one window, moving the mouse up causes the orbit to go left, in the other window, it goes down, in the other, it goes right.  This is the same for moving the mouse in any direction, the way it gets transposed is off.

Comment: Could it be the that your `GameObject` eastCamera is the same in every instance of the game? What I mean is First player gets eastCamera, but second player also gets the same eastCamera as a `GameObject`. Could you debug the second player and confirm that?

Comment: I don't think so.  Each camera is pointed in different direction, all around a "table".  When in the game, I can see they are all looking at a different part of the room.  But, one thing that I noticed is that all the camera scripts have the same values for the public variables.

Comment: But thats what I meant to say, that they are different but they all think that they are one camera.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139959/discussion-between-hristo-and-jason).

Comment: hey look at the chat :)